# Autenticação por LDAP, retorna true se a senha for null

Tags: php

Autenticação por LDAP parece ter um bug.

---

#### Script

```
# Dados do servidor
$server = '192.168.0.1';
$domain = '@meudominio.dom';
$port    = 389;

# Dados para acesso
$auth_user = 'rbz';
$auth_pass = '123';

# Criando conexão
$ldap_conn = ldap_connect($server, $port) or exit('Erro na conexão');
if (!$ldap_conn) exit('Falha na conexão');

# Bind
$bind = @ldap_bind($ldap_conn, $auth_user.$domain, $auth_pass) or exit("Erro em bind");
if (!$bind) exit('Usuário e/ou senha incorreto(s)!');
```

---

#### Problema

Se caso o valor de `$auth_pass` for *nulo*, o retorno é true. Independente do usuário, ou até mesmo usuário *nulo*.

---

#### Dúvida

- Por que o `@ldap_bind` retorna `true` quando a senha é *null*?
- Como evitar essa falha?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conforme definido na [RFC 4513](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4513).

[5.1.1.  Anonymous Authentication Mechanism of Simple Bind](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4513#section-5.1.1)

> An LDAP client may use the anonymous authentication mechanism of the
> simple Bind method to explicitly establish an anonymous authorization
> state by sending a Bind request with a name value of zero length and
> specifying the simple authentication choice containing a password
> value of zero length.

Traduzindo, quando se utiliza uma credencial válida (usuário) e se utiliza uma senha de tamanho zero (ou sem enviar senha), é realizada uma autorização anônima.

Essa autorização, do ponto de vista do LDAP, é configurada para ser permitida e pode ser limitada, pois, algumas operações podem não ser permitidas através de autenticações anônimas.

Você pode configurar o servidor para rejeitar esses tipos de configurações ou adicionar a validação do tamanho de senha em conjunto.

```
$bind = @ldap_bind($ldap_conn, $auth_user.$domain, $auth_pass) or exit("Erro em bind");
if (!$bind || strlen(trim($auth_pass)) == 0) exit('Usuário e/ou senha incorreto(s)!');
```

Existem, além, outros tipos de mecanismos como por exemplo o "Mecanismo de Autenticação não Autenticada", onde não se utiliza nem usuário e nem senha para o bind:

[5.1.2.  Unauthenticated Authentication Mechanism of Simple Bind](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4513#section-5.1.1)

> An LDAP client may use the unauthenticated authentication mechanism of the simple Bind method to establish an anonymous authorization state by sending a Bind request with a name value (a distinguished name in LDAP string form [RFC4514] of non-zero length) and specifying the simple authentication choice containing a password value of zero length.

Se o teu servidor LDAP permitir isso, você também deverá configurá-lo ou tratar em código.